# How to show other column on label/textbox from DB when click choose on dropdownlist without valuefield or textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Assume I have table is `tbl_AAA` contains columns.

```
ID , Firstname , Lastname , Nickname ,tel
```

Then I  `SELECT * FROM tbl_AAA` to bind data on dropdownlist.
and set

```
DataValueField = "ID" and  DataTextField = "Firstname"
```

I need to show other column from database when I click choose anything on dropdownlist such as

[image]

Comment: just show your entire code to fill `dropdownlist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make dropdown property isPostback="true" then add below method

```
 protected void dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
              if (dropdown.SelectedIndex != 0) {
            SqlStr = "Select Nickname  From tbl_AAA  where ID =@ID";
           //Execute above query and result text assign to label/textbox
            SqlConnection connection = new          SqlConnection("Server=ServerNAme;Initial Catalog=DBName; User ID=sa;Password=Password;");
               SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SqlStr, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Conversion.Val(dropdown.SelectedValue));

lbl.text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: //Execute above query and result text assign to label/textbox.
Where are label.txt / textbox.txt ?

Comment: You want to display result instead of  'Show NickName Here' so 'Show NickName Here' is your label...take one label near dropdown and show result in that label

Comment: i know and i have label near dropdown.
But your code not have some `lbl.text` put in your code

Answer (score 0):

Which version of HTML are you using?

In HTML 5, it is totally valid to have custom attributes prefixed with data-, e.g.

`<div data-nickname="lol"><`/div>

In XHTML, this is not really valid. If you are in XHTML 1.1 mode, the browser will probably complain about it, but in 1.0 mode, most browsers will just silently ignore it.

If I were you, I would follow the script based approach. You could make it automatically generated on server side so that it's not a pain in the back to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectedIndexChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) with `AutoPostBack = true` for that. Here your following path;

- Let's assume your `<--Choose Name-->` item is `-1` indexed, you can check your `SelectedIndex` is `-1` or not.
- If your selected index is not `-1`, create and `SqlConnection` with `SqlCommand` and use `SELECT Nickname FROM tbl_AAA WHERE ID = @id` and put your `SelectedValue` of your dropdownlist to this `@id` with [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).
- I *assume* your `ID` is distinct value on your table, execute your query with `ExecuteScalar` and get `Nickname` as an `object`, cast is to `string` and assign this string to this label `Text` property.

As an exmaple;

```
void DropDownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(DropDownlist1.SelectedIndex != -1)
   {
       using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
       using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
       {
             cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Nickname FROM tbl_AAA WHERE ID = @id";
             cmd.Paramerters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
                            .Value = int.Parse(DropDownlist1.SelectedValue);
             con.Open();
             Label1.Text = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       Label1.Text = string.Empty;
   }
}
```

Comment: conString is not declared !
how to declare conString

Comment: @bogey020 It is your connection string to that database.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format error 
@Soner Gönül